# Convert existing table to temporal table with computed column (User-defined Function)

Tags: sql, sql-server, user-defined-functions, calculated-columns, temporal-tables

I want to convert my existing table to a temporal table and it has 2 computed columns (user-defined function).

I've already added the 3 columns to my table using the script below and it was successful.

```
Alter Table Trips
Add StartTime DateTime2 (2) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW START HIDDEN
        constraint df_StartTime default DateAdd(second, -1, SYSUTCDATETIME()),
    EndTime DateTime2 (2) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW END HIDDEN
        constraint df_EndTime default '9999.12.31 23:59:59.99',
    Period For System_Time (StartTime, EndTime)
Go
```

But when I'm trying to execute the script below

```
Alter Table Trips
    SET(SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON (HISTORY_TABLE = dbo.Trips_History))
Go
```

I'm getting the error below

```
Msg 13585, Level 16, State 1, Line 19
Computed column is defined with a user-defined function which is not allowed with system-versioned table 'AccessBetaX.dbo.Trips' because it performs user or system data access, or is assumed to perform this access. A function is assumed by default to perform data access if it is not schemabound.
```

Did I miss something important?

Comment: What's the structure of Trips_History table? History table should not contain any computed columns, define them as usual columns with proper type